# Why do I get a roscd: No such package/stack ’test_pub_sub/src’ error when I run roscd?

Tags: linux, nodes, ros, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to create 2 nodes shared a string message in a custom package. I use ubuntu 20.04 and ROS noetic

After installing ROS. I did do the following steps:

1. I have created a catkin workspace
2. created a package
3. installed the package to standard messages
4. Compile the catkin workspace

When I then tried to source the environment, I got an `roscd: No such package/stack ’test_pub_sub/src’` error. What I did was running the following commands:

```sh
cd catkin_ws 
source devel/setup.bash 
roscd 'test_pub_sub/src/'
```

[image: erorr message]

My workspace looks like this

[image: workspace]

Comment: can you show us your workspace and be more specific?

Comment: I have upload the workspace folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I solved it with this command:`catkin_create_pkg package_name` inside the src folder on your workspace.